# Dynamic redirect subdomain to domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, duplicates, subdomain, redirect

I added a new domain (sub.fr) with cpanel and it add auto a subdomain (sub.maindomain.com)

I found how to redirect this subdomain to domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

But I still have an issue with all internal links:

For example: **https://sub.maindomain.com/contact** will not redirect to **https://sub.fr/contact**

I need to find a way to dynamically redirect all links from subdomain to their respective links from domain otherwise it will create duplicate content and hurt my SEO.

Comment: You probably should add another tag to this, such as [tag:apache].  I didn't actually do that for you since I'm not sure that's what you're using, and also because the tag says that for configuration questions, you might do better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) than on SO.  The number of views you've gotten (9 in 5 hours) indicates that not many people are tracking the chosen tags actively.  (None of them are tags I normally look at.)

Comment: Thank you Johnathan, i add apache and htaccess in my tags